# Help to convert this sql query to 'JOIN' syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am new to SQL. Can someone help to convert this query, so it uses join syntax?

```
SELECT groups.name,
       users.firstname,
       users.lastname,
       users.emailaddress,
       groupmembers.userid,
       reminders.groupid,
       reminders.ownerid,
       reminderdetails.recno,
       reminderdetails.cardid,
       reminderdetails.message
FROM   reminderdetails,
       reminders,
       groupmembers,
       users,
       groups
WHERE  assocdate = 'Y'
       AND ( reminder1 != 99
             AND ( Datediff(reminderdate, '2011-09-22') = reminder1 )
              OR ( reminder2 != 99
                   AND Datediff(reminderdate, '2011-09-22') = reminder2 ) )
       AND reminders.cardid = reminderdetails.cardid
       AND groupmembers.groupid = reminders.groupid
       AND groupmembers.sendemail = 'Y'
       AND users.recno = groupmembers.userid
       AND groups.recno = reminders.groupid
```

Comment: What are `assocdate`, `reminder1`, `reminder2`, and `reminderdate`? I mean, are all of them variables?

Comment: @Andriy: They are columns in table remiderdetails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT g.name,
       uu.firstname,
       uu.lastname,
       uu.emailaddress,
       gp.userid,
       rm.groupid,
       rm.ownerid,
       rd.recno,
       rd.cardid,
       rd.message
FROM   reminderdetails rd
JOIN   reminders rm on rm.cardid=rd.cardId
JOIN   groupmembers gp on gp.groupid=rm.groupId and gp.sendemail='Y'
JOIN   users uu on uu.recNo=gp.userId,
JOIN   groups g ON g.recno=rm.groupId
WHERE  assocdate = 'Y'
       AND ( reminder1 != 99
             AND ( Datediff(reminderdate, '2011-09-22') = reminder1 )
              OR ( reminder2 != 99
                   AND Datediff(reminderdate, '2011-09-22') = reminder2 ) )
```

Comment: I am not sure whether MySQL allows one to mix table names with the same table's aliases when referencing columns, but in any event, if you have defined an alias for a table, why use the original name instead? I'm talking about references in the SELECT clause of your query.

Comment: For completeness, no you can't use the original table name if you've aliased it. This goes for any alias (I think); if you alias a column its original name is no longer available, and so on.

Comment: @Joe: Depends on what you mean. For example, you can alias columns in the SELECT clause and still reference them by their original names in ORDER BY. But if you meant accessing columns of a subselect from the outer select, then yes, you can only reference aliased columns by their aliases, not by their 'real' names. And thanks for the confirmation about table aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a guess without knowing your table structure, but I think this seems about right.

Edit: Just seen the other one; I'd generally prefer to not load up the JOIN with too many clauses, as you end up going hunting all over the place when you want to find out what WHERE clauses are being applied. If possible, I think it's better to keep JOINs containing just the JOIN and put the rest into the WHERE.

I'm sure someone else can come along and shoot me down on that one, but that's my take on it :)

```
SELECT groups.name,
       users.firstname,
       users.lastname,
       users.emailaddress,
       groupmembers.userid,
       reminders.groupid,
       reminders.ownerid,
       reminderdetails.recno,
       reminderdetails.cardid,
       reminderdetails.message
FROM   groups
INNER JOIN groupmembers ON groups.groupid = groupmembers.groupid
INNER JOIN users ON groupmembers.userid = users.userid
INNER JOIN reminders ON users.userid = reminders.ownderid
INNER JOIN reminderdetails ON reminders.cardid = reminderdetails.cardid
WHERE  assocdate = 'Y'
       AND ( reminder1 != 99
             AND ( Datediff(reminderdate, '2011-09-22') = reminder1 )
              OR ( reminder2 != 99
                   AND Datediff(reminderdate, '2011-09-22') = reminder2 ) )
AND groupmembers.sendemail = 'Y'
```